# Using regexp in org-refile-targets and the `:refile-targets` property in org-capture-templates

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-refile

I am trying to specify a refile target with a regexp, but can't get it to work. Specifically, I'm trying to use the new `:refile-targets` property in `org-capture-templates`, but this question holds for using regexps in `org-refile-targets` as well.

---

Since version 9.5, org mode comes with the `:refile-targets` org-capture-templates property. The [description](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-capture.el#L250-L252) reads:

> When exiting capture mode via `org-capture-refile`, the variable `org-refile-targets` will be temporarily bound to the value of this property.

In theory, `org-refile-targets` allows to set targets [via regexp](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-refile.el#L81-L82):

> a cons cell (:regexp . "REGEXP") with a regular expression matching headlines that are refiling targets.

---

I want to set :refile-targets to the parts of the current file indicated with `<---`:

```
* Undesirable heading
** Targets

* Desirable heading
** Targets                 <---- this whole subtree is a desirable target
** Subheading
*** Targets                <---- this whole subtree is a desirable target
```

---

This is my capture template:

```
(("c" "Capture")
("ce" "Capture example")
entry
(file "path/to/file")
"* %^{prompt}"
:refile-targets REFILE_TARGET_DISCUSSED_BELOW)
```

---

These are representative examples of regexps that I have tried:

1. `((nil :regexp . "Targets"))` obviously includes the undesirable `Undesirable heading` subtree
2. `((nil :regexp . "Desirable heading.*Targets"))` does not return anything
3. `((nil :regexp . "Desirable heading\\.\\*Targets"))` does not return anything

---

Details:

- In org-refile-targets, the syntax is `setq org-refile-targets '((nil :regexp . "REGEXP"))`, while in org-capture-templates the syntax is `:refile-targets ((nil :regexp . "REGEXP"))` (without the quote)
- The regexp in 3. was constructed with [rx](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rx-Notation.html) because the [only example](https://github.com/rougier/emacs-gtd/blob/5e712bbe2ab26d66bcf8e8c48f3d2bec536f2f67/GTD.org#L807) of complex :regexp in the wild that I have found used rx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that this regexp can't work: the regexp option parses headings (`Targets`), not the olp (`Desirable heading/Targets`).

The solution might lie in [`org-refile-targets-verify-function`](https://github.com/emacs-straight/org-mode/blob/main/lisp/org-refile.el#L113-L127).